# Reverse has_one relationship with ActiveRecord in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one

I'm going to pull my hair out here.

I have the following two tables:

```
databases
---------
id
user_id
driver
host
port
database_name
username_encryption_id
password_encryption_id

encryptions
-----------
id
encryption
salt
```

Using a Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord association, **I want to be able to do this**:

```
database = Database.find_by_id(database_id)
encryption = database.username_encryption
```

I'm pretty sure this is a has_one relationship (database has one username encryption). None of these work:

```
has_one :password_encryption, :class_name => "Encryption", :foreign_key => :password_encryption_id, :inverse_of => :encryption
has_one :username_encryption, :inverse_of => :database
```

**How do I get this working?** I'm dying here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a `belongs_to` association, since the `database` has the `username_encryption_id`:

```
class UsernameEncryption < Encryption
  has_one :database
end

class Database
  belongs_to :username_encryption
end
```

Comment: Ah, so the belongs_to goes in the model containing the foreign key. This worked: belongs_to :username_encryption, :class_name => "Encryption", :foreign_key => :username_encryption_id